# Need help subtracting time and date with Google SCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have this code here:

```
var date = a.created_at_timestamp.substring(0,10)
var time = a.created_at_timestamp.substring(11,19)
```

And both these values return strings with these values:

```
date = 2020-05-19 // 
Time = 17:00:08
```

I need to subtract 3 hours since it's coming in GMT time and I'm on GMT-3. Therefore, I thought about adding them together, subtracting three hours, and putting them apart again. Something like:

```
Orig Date: 20/05/19 // 
Orig Time: 20:15:19
```

```
Time + Date: 20/05/19 20:15 // 
Time + Date - 3h: 20/05/19 17:15
```

```
New Date: 20/05/19 00:00 // 
New Time: 17:15:19
```

I tried converting it to milliseconds as suggested in other post here, doing with formulas, where a function would trigger formulas adding both cells, which I was able to do, but couldn't tear them apart together. In addition, if possible, I'd like to do it inside the script.

Can someone help me with that?
I'm new at this and I'm somewhat used to VBA. Tried some things from VBA, but they don't really apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having separate strings for date and time, it'd likely be easier to just create a new `Date` object with both combined.

```
var dateTime = new Date(a.created_at_timestamp.substring(0,19));
```

You can then subtract 3 hours by doing:

```
var timeOffset = 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 3hrs of millis

var offsetDate = new Date(dateTime.getTime() - timeOffset);
```